# Libgdx - Getting an error when using TexturePacker

Tags: java, android-studio, libgdx, assets, texturepacker

I am new to Libgdx and have been following a book 'Learning LibGDX Game Development, 2nd Edition' for learning, and to let you now I am using Android Studio, the problem is even though I can create pack files in the android asset folder somehow I get an GdxRuntimeException error that says Asset not loaded. Error log is as shown below:

```
    images
    cloud02 (alias of cloud01)
    cloud03 (alias of cloud01)
    Packing.........
    Writing 1024x1024: C:\Users\Raghab\AndroidStudioProjects\CanyonBunnyTest\android\assets\images\canyonbunny.pack.png
    com.packtpub.libgdx.canyonbunny.game.Assets: No of assets loader: 2
    com.packtpub.libgdx.canyonbunny.game.Assets: Asset: C:/Users/Raghab/AndroidStudioProjects/CanyonBunnyTest/android/assets/images/canyonbunny.pack.png
    com.packtpub.libgdx.canyonbunny.game.Assets: Asset: C:/Users/Raghab/AndroidStudioProjects/CanyonBunnyTest/android/assets/images/canyonbunny.pack.atlas
    Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Asset not loaded: C:\Users\Raghab\AndroidStudioProjects\CanyonBunnyTest\android\assets\images\canyonbunny.pack.atlas
        at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.get(AssetManager.java:110)
        at com.packtpub.libgdx.canyonbunny.game.Assets.init(Assets.java:53)
        at com.packtpub.libgdx.canyonbunny.CanyonBunnyMain.create(CanyonBunnyMain.java:30)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:143)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)

    Process finished with exit code 0
```

It seems even though the pack and image file is created on the Asset folder I get an exception on the next line saying it can't find it, the paths are absolute and doesn't seem to be a problem, I have pasted the classes that are used.

Desktop Class:

```
package com.packtpub.libgdx.canyonbunny.desktop;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;
import com.badlogic.gdx.tools.texturepacker.TexturePacker;
import com.packtpub.libgdx.canyonbunny.CanyonBunnyMain;

public class DesktopLauncher {

    private static boolean rebuildAtlas = true;
    private static boolean drawDebugOutline = true;

    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        if (rebuildAtlas) {
            TexturePacker.Settings settings = new TexturePacker.Settings();
            settings.maxWidth = 1024;
            settings.maxHeight = 1024;
            settings.duplicatePadding = false;
            settings.debug = drawDebugOutline;

            TexturePacker.process(settings, "C:\\Users\\Raghab\\AndroidStudioProjects\\CanyonBunnyTest\\desktop\\assets-raw\\images", "C:\\Users\\Raghab\\AndroidStudioProjects\\CanyonBunnyTest\\android\\assets\\images", "canyonbunny.pack");

        }
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        config.title = "CanyonBunny";
        config.useGL30 = false;
        config.width = 800;
        config.height = 480;

        new LwjglApplication(new CanyonBunnyMain(), config);
    }
}
```

Assets Class:

```
package com.packtpub.libgdx.canyonbunny.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetDescriptor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetErrorListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Disposable;
import com.packtpub.libgdx.canyonbunny.util.Constants;

public class Assets implements Disposable, AssetErrorListener {

    public static final String TAG = Assets.class.getName();

    public static final Assets instance = new Assets();

    private AssetManager assetManager;

    private Assets() {

    }

    public AssetBunny bunny;
    public AssetRock rock;
    public AssetGoldCoin goldCoin;
    public AssetFeather feather;
    public AssetLevelDecoration levelDecoration;


    public void init(AssetManager assetManager) {
        this.assetManager = assetManager;
        assetManager.setErrorListener(this);

        assetManager.load(Constants.TEXTURE_ATLAS_OBJECTS, TextureAtlas.class);
        assetManager.finishLoading();

        Gdx.app.debug(TAG, "No of assets loader: " + assetManager.getAssetNames().size);
        for (String a : assetManager.getAssetNames()) {
            Gdx.app.debug((TAG), "Asset: " + a);;
        }

        TextureAtlas atlas = assetManager.get(Constants.TEXTURE_ATLAS_OBJECTS);
        for (Texture t : atlas.getTextures()) {
            t.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
        }

        bunny = new AssetBunny(atlas);
        rock = new AssetRock(atlas);
        goldCoin = new AssetGoldCoin(atlas);
        feather = new AssetFeather(atlas);
        levelDecoration = new AssetLevelDecoration(atlas);

    }  
    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        assetManager.dispose();

    }
    @Override
    public void error(AssetDescriptor asset, Throwable throwable) {
        Gdx.app.error((TAG), "Couldn't load asset '" + asset.fileName + "'", (Exception) throwable);;
    }

    public class AssetBunny {
        public final TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion head;


        public AssetBunny(TextureAtlas atlas) {
            head = atlas.findRegion("bunny_head");

        }
    }

    public class AssetRock {
        public final TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion edge;
        public final TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion middle;

        public AssetRock(TextureAtlas atlas) {
            edge = atlas.findRegion("rock_edge");
            middle = atlas.findRegion("rock_middle");
        }
    }

    public class AssetGoldCoin {
        public final TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion goldCoin;

        public AssetGoldCoin(TextureAtlas atlas) {
            goldCoin = atlas.findRegion("item_gold_coin");
        }
    }

    public class AssetFeather {
        public final TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion feather;

        public AssetFeather(TextureAtlas atlas) {
            feather = atlas.findRegion("item_feather");
        }
    }
    public class AssetLevelDecoration {
        public final TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion cloud01;
        public final TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion cloud02;
        public final TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion cloud03;
        public final TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion mountainLeft;
        public final TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion mountainRight;
        public final TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion waterOverlay;

        public AssetLevelDecoration(TextureAtlas atlas) {
            cloud01 = atlas.findRegion("cloud01");
            cloud02 = atlas.findRegion("cloud02");
            cloud03 = atlas.findRegion("cloud03");
            mountainLeft = atlas.findRegion("mountain_left");
            mountainRight = atlas.findRegion("mountain_Right");
            waterOverlay = atlas.findRegion("water_overlay");
        }
    }

}
```

Constant Class:

```
package com.packtpub.libgdx.canyonbunny.util;

public class Constants {
    public static final float VIEWPORT_WIDTH = 5.0f;

    public static final float VIEWPORT_HEIGHT = 5.0f;

    public static final String TEXTURE_ATLAS_OBJECTS =
            "C:\\Users\\Raghab\\AndroidStudioProjects\\CanyonBunnyTest\\android\\assets\\images\\canyonbunny.pack.atlas";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry all..it's android studio that's not treating the path correctly. Use forward slash instead of back slash when defining the paths..took me a day to figure out.